# Why hide armor?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

In Skyrim, hide armor is made from the same materials as leather armor and, if memory serves, leather beats hide in every category by the numbers.  Hide has a shield and leather does not, but other than that, what's the point?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Hide armor is practically inferior in every way, and there's no reason to buy it or craft it unless you're going for the "hide armor" look.

It weighs *slightly* less, but not really enough to make a difference.

Comment: that's pretty much how I saw it but I was unsure if I was missing something, you guys tend to be much more fluent in skyrimese than I am so I asked to clarify. Thanks!

Comment: I seem to recall hide armor having an amazing weight:value ratio for looting, but I may have a faulty memory here.

Comment: @LessPop_MoreFizz Nah, it's worth about 10x its weight.  Leather's worth 20x+.

Comment: It was another one of the armor types favored by bandits then. /shrug.